# adding jar files to sunspot solr

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

We are currently using sunspot 1.3.3 gem. We configured solr spellchecker component with JaroWinklerDistance as below in solrConfig.xml. However, it results in ClassNotFoundException. How do we handle this? Is there some specific directory where we need to copy the jar file? How does one configure jetty/solr that is managed through sunspot?

> ```
> <lst name="spellchecker">
>      <str name="name">jarowinkler</str>
>      <str name="field">spell</str>
>      <str name="distanceMeasure">
>        org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance
>      </str>
>      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
> </lst>
> ```

We have already tried putting lucene-spellchecker**.jar under rails_app_root/solr/lib and it doesn't work.

Thanks

exception stacktrace

> HTTP ERROR: 500
>
> Severe errors in solr configuration.
>
> Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be
>   wrong.
>
> If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:
>
> false
>
> in null
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class '
>              org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance
>            '    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.spelling.AbstractLuceneSpellChecker.init(AbstractLuceneSpellChecker.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.spelling.IndexBasedSpellChecker.init(IndexBasedSpellChecker.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.inform(SpellCheckComponent.java:274)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:486)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:588)  at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:99)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:594)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:210)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:929)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)     at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)  at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)   at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>              org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance
>                 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)     at
>   java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:357)
>     ... 32 more RequestURI=/solr/admin/
>
> Powered by Jetty://

Comment: can you past the full exception ??

Comment: @Jayendra i have updated question with exception stacktrace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class should be included in one of the following jars :-

- solr-lucene-spellchecker-X.X.0.jar
- lucene-spellchecker-X.X.0.jar

So you can confirm if the jar is included in the classpath when solr starts up and loads external jars.
If you are executing it in Jetty, you can update the [lib](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#lib) directives in SolrConfig.xml to look into the lib where the library exists.

You can also want to look at this [Interesting thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201108.mbox/%3C4E4CB17C.9040204@gmx.de%3E).

Putting it on a single line :-

```
<str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance</str>
```

Comment: thanks for the link to that thread.. wasted three hrs on this issue

Comment: I could not find those jars in the lib directory. Where could I download them?